# Translating SQL results to LINq with join of literal

Tags: sql, linq, join

All,
  This is my first post to this forum and I have searched all throughout this site to find an answer to my question, but it looks like there is not an example of what I need to do.

Below is a SQL query I need to adapt to a LINQ statement:

```
select COUNT(pe2.*)
from SomeTable pe1 
inner join SomeTable pe2 on (pe2.Id=pe1.Id and pe2.TypeCode='X')
where pe1.TypeCode='Y'
```

I have tried to join this as illustrated below, but it doesn't work:

```
var query = (from pe2 in SomeTable
         join pe1 in SomeTable
         on new { pe1.Id } equals new {pe2.Id }
         where pe2.TypeCode == "X" 
         && pe1.TypeCode == "Y"
         select pe2).Count();
```

Comment: you're not doing a count in your sql query.. why add it in your linq query ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that part.  What I am trying to do is basically check to see if there are any rows returned.  The SQL select can be changed to SELECT COUNT(pe2.*)

Comment: If you just want to know **if** there are any rows, not how many there really are -- i.e., if you don't care whether it's one row or 500 -- then the `Any()` method is a better fit than `Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `TypeCode` is HardCoded you can pass it to the `where` clause

```
select pe2.*
from SomeTable pe1 
inner join SomeTable pe2 on pe2.Id=pe1.Id
where pe1.TypeCode='Y'
and pe2.TypeCode='X'
```

And here it's how I would do it in `linq`

```
var l1 = new List<dynamic> { new { Id = 1, Code = "X" }, new { Id = 2, Code = "Y" } };
var l2 = new List<dynamic> { new { Id = 1, Code = "Y" }, new { Id = 2, Code = "X" } };

//lambda expression
l1.Join(l2, 
        x => x.Id, 
        y => y.Id, 
       (x, y) => new { Pe1 = x,  Pe2 = y })
  .Where(x => x.Pe1.Code == "Y" && x.Pe2.Code == "X")
  .Select(x => x.Pe2);

//query...
from x in l1
join y  in l2 on x.Id equals y.Id
where x.Code == "Y" 
&& y.Code == "X"
select y

from x in l1
from y in l2
where x.Id == y.Id
&& x.Code == "Y"
&& y.Code == "X"
select y
```